# List of Days irrespective of time

Tags: c#, linq

I have an `ObservableCollection` of a Type with a property "StartDate" of type `DateTime`.
I want to create a list of Unique Days irrespective of the time. I know I can do this iterating over the list and comparing day,month,year of a date. But is there any cleaner & simpler way of doing this? may be through `LINQ` or something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DateTime` has a property [`Date`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx) that doesn't contain the time of day, just the date.
First select it and then use [`Distinct`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436.aspx) to get each date only once.

```
var uniqueDays = collection.Select(x => x.StartDate.Date).Distinct();
```